# 1D Simplex Noise Returns Same Generation

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, simplex-noise

I've been using 1D Simplex Noise to create a random world surface, and it keeps generating with the same looking surface terrain, with some minor variations.  Here is my sample code-

```
Tile[][] tiles = new Tile[rows][];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    tiles[i] = new Tile[cols];
    for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
    {
        tiles[i][x] = new Tile(0, new Vector2(x, i), scale);
    }
}

int left = Main.rand.Next(rows / 4, rows / 2);

double seed = Main.rand.NextDouble();
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    int height = left + (int)(Noise.Generate((float)seed) * 10);
    height = (int)MathHelper.Clamp(height, 0, rows - 1);
    tiles[height][i] = new Tile(2, new Vector2(i, height), scale);
    //FillLower just fills everything under the top tile
    FillLower(tiles, height, i, scale);
    seed += .05f;
}
```

My question is am I doing something wrong with the Simplex Noise method?  How should I generate it so it'll look different?

Images for reference- http://imgur.com/I0g98z8,M61UBfb,tYPflb7

Comment: The Noise class documentation may be usefull.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/simplexnoise/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double seed = Main.rand.NextDouble();
```

give you a 0..1 double value

```
(float)seed) * 10
```

give you a 0..10  value

```
seed += .05f;
```

give a little delta.

Try

```
double seed = Main.rand.NextDouble() * 255.0; //or greater
...
int height = left + (int)(Noise.Generate((float)seed) );
...
seed += 1.0; //play with this increment
```

Comment: When I do it this way, I just get a straight line for my terrain generation.

Comment: Whoops, figured it out (I think).